# can't set field value Input antd javascript/reactjs

Tags: javascript, forms, antd

I have function when click button it will generate password and set value for Input, but when i add field `name="password"` in the `Form.Item`  it can't work

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Input, Form, Button } from "antd";
 const App = () => {
  const [generatePW, setGeneratePW] = useState("");

  //Generate Password
  const generatePassword = () => {
    let length = 10;
    let charset =
      "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    let retVal = "";
    for (let i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
      retVal += charset.charAt(Math.random() * n);
    }
    setGeneratePW(retVal);
  };

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onFinish={onFinish}>
        <Form.Item name="password">
          <Input.Password placeholder="Basic usage" value={generatePW} />
        </Form.Item>
        <Button onClick={generatePassword}>Click</Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, i have change the question, pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `fields` prop of [`Form`](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form) like `fields={[{ name: "password", value: generatePW }]}` in order to manage the state externally.
Your final code will be like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Input, Form, Button } from "antd";
const App = () => {
  const [generatePW, setGeneratePW] = useState("");

  //Generate Password
  const generatePassword = () => {
    let length = 10;
    let charset =
      "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    let retVal = "";
    for (let i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
      retVal += charset.charAt(Math.random() * n);
    }
    setGeneratePW(retVal);
  };

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        fields={[{ name: "password", value: generatePW }]}
        onFinish={onFinish}
      >
        <Form.Item name="password">
          <Input.Password
            value={generatePW}
            onChange={(e) => setGeneratePW(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Item>
        <Button onClick={generatePassword}>Click</Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/antd-generate-password?file=src%2FApp.jsx) for a live working example of this solution.